# What in-app advertising framework should I use?

Tags: android, admob, adsense, ads, mopub

I'm a little confused about what in-app advertising model to use in my Android app. I've Googled, searched stackoverflow, but no definitive answer. There seems to be a few solutions out there but AdSense, AdMob generation one and generation two seems to be most popular. Could someone with knowledge explain the difference between them and when to use one or the other although I'm open to other solutions to. For the record I'm developing an app with streamed video.

Comment: http://tap.me/ if you're developing games :D

Answer (score 4):

[MoPub](http://www.mopub.com/) serves ads and also aggregates and serves ads from other advertisers, and I've had good fill rates and stability with them.

Comment: Well. If I choose the wrong framwork it'll be a bad choice of code so for me it's a programming question.

Comment: @user1160807 -- no, that does not make it a programming question.

Comment: @mah -- sorry but your wrong. It fits nicely according to the FAQ.

Comment: @HoratioCain Thanks for the answer. I did try to dig up some pros and cons for different frameworks and in the end I'll go for your suggestion. Very much because it's open source. I'd vote for your answer if I could but I need 15 reputations to do that so you'll have to settle with my thanx. I'll get back when I have more ;)

Answer (score 0):

Both Admob and Adsense are good options depending on what you are looking to do. Admob Is a mobile network and Adsense works with Digital. However, I have heard many of our publishers complain about low fill rates and average eCPMs  or vice versa, as well as poor publisher support. I would recommend Tapit. We've seen great results in terms of Fillrates (90%) and good eCPMs. We operate very similar to Admob but pride our selves in giving excellent support as well as working with high Quality advertisers.

Answer (score 0):

I am using currently in my application published on Google, AdMob and AirPush SDK system.

I can say you that AdMob is based on banner inside your application , you can click on this banner only running your app while AirPush is based on different advertiser technics, push notification, SmartWall and Icon Push.

AirPush is an invasive system because you will receive notifications , icon link on your home desktop even if your app is not running.

Anyway I prefer AirPush because it has  high fill rates and high eCPMs ..translated for you : you get more money than AdMob ( low fill rates and average eCPMs )

AirPush system and support is very professional even if some user don't like this kind of approach.

Answer (score 0):

If its a game or lengthy video i would suggest alternating between multiple ad networks. AdMob is best still. No other Ad Network match their Fill Rate or eCPM. But i feel AdMob restricts eCPM after one stage. So i am currently trying to integrate multiple ad notworks showing in same place one after another after every 30 sec. Will post the result after few days.